# how to retrieve the other values in the business entity

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

The method has a return type of collection<**businessEntity**>. I am calling the method from the aspx page in order to populate a drop down -> **ddlDropDown**. I am binding he **DataTextField** of the **ddlDropDown** with the **BusinessEntity.Name**  and the **DataValueField** with **BusinessEntity.Id**, the business entity contains another id which is **BusinessEntity.ProductId**. I need to use the **ProductId** of the value selected in the drop down list in the code behind. Can you help suggest how I can do so?

One possible way could be to call the method in the page_Load on the code behind and save the collection in a hidden variable and when required do a loop through in the hidden variable and retrieve the selected value **Product Id**.

Your thoughts please.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly accomplish this using a hidden field.

Here's another idea: bind the DataValueField to a special derived string, containing the BusinessEntity.Id AND the BusinessEntity.ProductId.

In other words, concatenate the BusinessEntity.Id and BusinessEntity.ProductId into a single string, seperated by the pipe ("|") symbol for example.

E.g to bind:

```
ddlFoo.DataValueField = string.Format("{0}|{1}", "Id", "ProductId");
```

Then to retrieve selected item:

```
var id = ddlFoo.SelectedValue.Split("|")[0];
var productId = ddlFoo.SelectedValue.Split("|")[1];
```

Saves you looping/matching. Again, its not ideal, but then again neither is binding multiple values types to a dropdownlist.